# Как работать в Selenium c динамически подгружаемыми кнопками и формами на веб-странице?

Tags: python, selenium

Суть такова - нужно с помощью Selenium выполнить вход в сбер, а если логин или пароль введён неправильно - нажать на восстановить доступ, но оно вот что-то не нажимается, хотя находится. Не бейте сильно, вчера только про Selenium узнал вообще.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://online.sberbank.ru/CSAFront/index.do')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginByLogin"]')
login.send_keys('мыавиывя')

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
password.send_keys('цуаывмфывпм')

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="homeAuth"]/div[3]/div/button')
submit.click()

time.sleep(3)

recover = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password-error"]/p/a')
recover.click()
```

Comment: 'нажать на восстановить доступ' через селениум перейди по этой ссылочке https://online.sberbank.ru/CSAFront/index.do#/restore

Comment: мне надо разобраться именно как через селениум имитировать пользовательские вводы и тд,  а так понятное дело, я сам много куда зайти могу